# CuRL response with Base64 encoded string is different to browser response

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm developing an addition to my iOS app that uses auto-renewing subscriptions. I get the IAP receipt in the app and send it to my server (PHP) to verify. I create the request to the Apple servers as below:

```
$json_receipt = json_encode(array(
    'receipt-data' => $my_receipt_from_app,
    'password' => $my_shared_secret_from_itunes_connect
));

$receipt_validation_response = validateiosreceipt($json_receipt);
```

...

```
function validateiosreceipt($json_receipt){

    $sandbox_verify_url = "https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $sandbox_verify_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_receipt);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $errno    = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg   = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

So this works, in that the original receipt gets POSTed to the Apple server, and I get a response in JSON format, which looks good. But, when I grab the "latest_receipt" field from the response to make a new request (as above) to get the last renewed subscription date, it fails with:

```
{"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"}
```

So, I use Postman in Chrome to recreate the original POST, and get the response, which looks similar, except for the "latest_receipt" field, which is different. So I manually grab this and try it, and it works.

So, CuRL appears to be doing something to the receipt string in the response. It should be Base64 encoded, so I'm wondering if it's re-encoding it somehow.

Here's the Postman response for "latest_receipt" (works):

```
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
```

And here's the "latest_receipt" field from the Curl response (doesn't work):

```
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
```

What I've tried so far:

In Postman, the response header includes "content-encoding -> gzip", so I tried to gzdecode() the "latest_receipt" field, but that didn't work. I also tried gzdeflate(), htmlspecialchars_decode() and urldecode(), but none of these worked.

So, I need some insight to why Curl is modifying this field in the response. Any ideas?